# ETH not showing in Coinbase Wallet after using Uniswap

Tags: etherscan, uniswap, uniswapv3

I used Uniswap to "swap" Boost Coin (was paid in this for assisting with the project) to ETH. To clarify, this was using the browser on Coinbase Wallet app, not regular coinable. When I look up the transaction hash it says the swap was successful, however the tokens never showed up in my wallet.

I have contacted Coinbase support and they don't have any answers.

Anyone have any idea what could have happened? Or any advice on how to get these tokens to show in my wallet?

Transaction Hash: 0x4ff94304152a481e9d3336e26fd959c149d4847e8b12dffdb9cc01f95709fd60

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The transaction shows that you swapped the tokens for Eth and you did received the Eth in your address (1.091778833710728356 Ether to be exact). Nothing seems wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I spoke with Coinbase support yesterday and they said the same thing. And said that since it is an ERC-20 token swapping to ETH that it doesn't show in your ETH transaction history, but does add to your wallet.